# Auto restarting asterisk and mysql using upstart

Tags: mysql, upstart, asterisk

I want `asterisk` and `mysql` to be able to auto-restart if anything were to happen to it, like if it crashed.

I found a guide with what I'm looking for, but it's written assuming that the `/etc/inittab` is in use. How would this guide translate to an upstart based version?

Here is the guide: [How To: Auto-Restart Asterisk](http://ahsantasneem.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-auto-restart-asterisk.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `respawn`-option to your upstart-job (for mysql or asterisk).

You may also **additionally** add the `respawn limit`-option:

`respawn limit COUNT INTERVAL`

"If the job is respawned more than COUNT times in INTERVAL seconds, it will be considered to be having deeper problems and will be stopped."

E.g.

```
respawn
respawn limit 3 60
```

So your process will be automatically restartet if it crashes, but if it crashes more than 3 times in 60 seconds, it will not be restarted any more.

Documentation: [Upstart-Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn)

Here is an example upstart-job for asterisk, taken from [http://www.digium.com/](http://svnview.digium.com/svn/asterisk/trunk/contrib/upstart/asterisk.user.conf)

```
# asterisk
#
# Upstart control file for the Asterisk PBX
#
# To install, rename this file to 'asterisk' and copy it to /etc/event.d/
# On Debian: copy to /etc/init/
#
# To start asterisk manually:
#     sudo start asterisk
#
# To stop asterisk manually:
#     sudo stop asterisk
#
# Asterisk is started with an "interactive console", though redirected
# to/from /dev/null . The concept of a main console is bad. OTOH, the main
# process should not detach from the console if we work with upstart and
# alike.
#
# The username 'asterisk' is currently hardwired here, and likewise the
# varrundir.
#

description "Asterisk PBX"
#version     "1.8"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop  on runlevel [!2345]

pre-start script
  # Since Ubuntu clears /var/run on reboot, create this before we try to start
  if [ ! -d /var/run/asterisk ]; then
    mkdir -p asterisk /var/run/asterisk
    chown asterisk: /var/run/asterisk
  fi
end script

respawn
exec /usr/sbin/asterisk -U asterisk -g -f
```

Comment: How do I create an upstart job for asterisk? It doesn't appear there is one in /etc/init/

Comment: example-job added. :)